# problems in loading options in ng-options using an array

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build a select box inside ui-grid. The problems are:

1. It adds an empty option.
2. If I select any other option then all the options are going off.

Please help me. The first problem is discussed here by so many people but I couldn't figure it out what's the problem, may be because I am loading the options from an array, am not getting the answer. Do remember I am writing this inside gridCtrl(ui-grid)

here is the HTML

```
<select ng-model="gridOptions">
      <option ng-repeat="item in gridOptions.paginationPageSizes" ng-selected="paginationPageSize" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

here is the SCRIPT

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    paginationPageSizes: [10, 25, 50, 100],
    paginationPageSize: 10,
    enablePaginationControls: false
};
```

Comment: Please edit and add more code or share a plunker

Comment: are you using kendo ui-grid

Comment: Usually you don't build the options in a select element like that. Here's a reference on how to do it using Angular: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 0):

Usually it adds a blank value at the top when the currently selected value doesn't match any of the values in your dropdown.  Often this is a typing issue - so the currently selected value is `1` and the dropdown recognises `"1"`, or some other issue.

Where in the grid are you putting this dropdown?  Is it on the same page as the grid, or actually inside the grid somewhere?  If inside the grid, you may need to access gridOptions using `grid.appScope.gridOptions`, refer http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_appScope